# simple SQL query but no idea on how to solve it

Tags: sql, db2

hey everyone I have two different tables:

> PS(size(primary key), price) Sales(....size,quantity, total_Price)

I tried to execute this statement:

```
 update Sales
                set total_Price = (select price from PS, Sales 
where Sales.size = PS.size )*Quantity;
```

but i get this error always

> SQL0811N The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or
>   VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.

I know that the error is because the sub query i used in the select statement returns more than one row, that's why i can't work. Can someone please help me solve this problem.

Comment: A particular size can have multiple prices? What determines which of multiple prices will be used in this case?

Comment: You need where clause in outer query as well in case you are updating particular record.

Comment: A suggestion:-Dont use Comma seperate joins. Its been ages they have been deprecated!

Comment: @showdev actually each size has a unique price

Comment: You might like UPDATE..FROM instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server

Comment: What platform are you using? Mysql? SQL Server? Oracle?...

Comment: Heh, nobody ever guesses DB2.   editted question to change tags (database is a generic tag, I removed it)

Comment: @Twelfth sorry for that.. anyways, can you help me with this?

Comment: I think that you are looking for something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20031177/2589202).  Here's [another doing joins on an update](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/6738.update-and-delete-with-subselects.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you joining in another sales table? My guess is that:

```
update Sales s
    set total_Price = (select ps.price * s.Quantity
                       from PS 
                       where s.size = PS.size);
```

will do what you want. Since ps.size is unique you should not get a SQL0811N

Comment: thank you very much.. this is what i exactly want, appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

For starters you can:

```
UPDATE sales SET total_Price = PS.price * Quantity
from PS, Sales where Sales.size = PS.size
```

May not be a great idea - if there's more than one matching value it'll pick an arbitrary winner (and Lennart's answer would raise an error, which in fact may be best here).  If size is 1-to-1 then this is equivalent to Lennart's answer.