# joining in an update in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I'm getting an error when trying an update with a join in db2 that 'inner' is not expected and that it is instead expecting 'set'.

Looking at the query I understand what it is saying but I'm confused: Can you not do a join in an update on DB2?

I'm usually using MySQL but this script has to run against a db2 database and I've never come across this issue but it seems like it should be correct using db2 for iseries 7.2

```
UPDATE data d
    inner join sales s
    ON d.sku_id = s.id
SET expire_date = (to_date(:SHIPDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') + 127 DAYS) ,
    quantity = cast(:QUANTITY as int)
WHERE d.custID = cast(:cust as int)
```

Comment: Use the MERGE statement instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update DB2 table with a join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022982/how-to-update-db2-table-with-a-join)

Comment: I looked at it but the format looks a little different. How exactly would I use a merge on this? i've only used a merge for upserts before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match IN db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285136/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match-in-db2)

Comment: I posted my IRL answer of SQL that works on a variety of DB flavors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists clause can be used on DB2 for Iseries update statement.  I just took the join and moved it to a where exists clause.  Your only updating one table with supplied values so this was easy transformation.

```
    UPDATE data d
        SET expire_date = (to_date(:SHIPDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') + 127 DAYS) ,
        quantity = cast(:QUANTITY as int)
    WHERE d.custID = cast(:cust as int)
    and exists ( 
    select s.id from 
     sales s
      where d.sku_id = s.id
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `from` clause in DB2:

```
UPDATE data d
    SET expire_date = (to_date(:SHIPDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') + 127 DAYS) ,
        quantity = cast(:QUANTITY as int)
FROM sales s
WHERE d.sku_id = s.id AND
      d.custID = cast(:cust as int);
```

Comment: I thought so too for some reason, but it says  keyword FROM is not expected

Comment: @TomN. . . . Alas, that probably depends on the version of DB2.